# String to Date conversion is losing time

Tags: java, date

Does anyone know why Date is losing time values when converting from String ? I cannot seem to figure this one out.

Here is what type of `SimpleDateFormat` I am using:

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a");
```

The date I am trying to convert is a String in the form :

```
 String dateString = "Mon 06/23/2014 03:00 PM";
```

And when I do the following:

```
    Date convertDateFromString = null;
    try{

         convertDateFromString = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
    }catch(ParseException ex){

       ex.printStackTrace();
    }

   System.out.println(convertDateFromString.getTime());
```

My output is: `1403496000000`

And the expected output is: `1403550000000`

Can someone help me understand why the time is not being parsed?

**Update - Solved** --->> with the help of Jon Skeet

now using this SimpleDateFormat

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
```

and now the output is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've specified `HH` in your format, which is the 24-hour format. But you've *also* got an AM/PM designator.

As such, "03:00 PM" doesn't make sense - it's simultaneously trying to represent 3am (03 in 24 hours) and 3pm (PM in the data).

It sounds like you probably want `hh` in the format string, as the 12-hour specifier.

That's *part* of the problem. Next up is the time zone. Your expected value (1403550000000) represents 2014-06-23 19:00:00Z. So presumably you're expecting to use a time zone which is currently 4 hours behind UTC.

Your *actual* value (1403496000000) at the moment is 2014-06-23 04:00:00Z... so it appears to being parsed in a time zone which is 1 hour behind UTC.

You need to work out which time zone that data is meant to be in, and specify it explicitly in the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: hahaha wow simple mistake, and results are devestating to logic. Especially since this is for reminders. Kind of need the time! Thanks so much, sometimes it takes a second set of eyes!

Comment: @inner_class7: Looking at the values, that wasn't all that was wrong. See my edit.

Comment: Ahh, i will give this a try as well. The one hour offset is because its currently daylight savings time in us, I believe. Thanks again